# Bootstrap: adapt column height to text length on mobile

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, responsive-design

I am trying to adapt the columns to the text length on **mobile** using the Bootstrap framework.

If you go mobile you can see that the text goes outside the columns.

Is possible to fix it?

I prepared here an example:

https://www.bootply.com/1adDvvRmVt

Here the Code:

```
<div class="container">

<div class="row">
<div class="col-md-6" style="margin-bottom: 20px;">

<div class="col-md-12" style="height:250px; background-color: red; color: white;text-align: center; font-size: 18px;">

    <i class="fa fa-play" aria-hidden="true" style="font-size: 50px; padding-top: 60px;"></i><br>

    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. consectetur adipiscing elit.

</div>

</div>

<div class="col-md-6">

<div class="col-md-12" style="height:250px; background-color: green; color: white;text-align: center; font-size: 18px;">

    <i class="fa fa-play" aria-hidden="true" style="font-size: 50px; padding-top: 60px;"></i><br>

      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. consectetur adipiscing elit.

 </div>
 </div>

 </div>

 </div>

 <div class="container" style="margin-top: 20px;">

 <div class="row">
<div class="col-md-6" style="margin-bottom: 20px;">

  <div class="col-md-12" style="height:250px; background-color: red; color: white;text-align: center; font-size: 18px;">

    <i class="fa fa-play" aria-hidden="true" style="font-size: 50px; padding-top: 60px;"></i><br>

    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.consectetur adipiscing elit.

 </div>

</div>

 <div class="col-md-6">

  <div class="col-md-12" style="height:250px; background-color: green; color: white;text-align: center; font-size: 18px;">

    <i class="fa fa-play" aria-hidden="true" style="font-size: 50px; padding-top: 60px;"></i><br>

    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. consectetur adipiscing elit.

</div>

</div>

</div>
```

Here a screenshot of the problem:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will solve your problem :

```
<div class="col-md-12" style="min-height: 250px;background-color: red;color: white;text-align: center;font-size: 18px;">
   <i class="fa fa-play" aria-hidden="true" style="font-size: 50px; padding-top: 60px;"></i><br>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. consectetur adipiscing elit      
</div>
```

What I have done is, that I have changed `height: 250px;` to `min-height: 250px;`

If you give the property `height: 250px;` then the browser will just give it a fixed height, no matter what is the height of your content. But if you give it a `min-height: 250px;` then the browser will set the height to minimum 250px and if the height of the content increases, the height of the box will also increase.

On a separate note, it is better to use a CSS file instead of giving inline styles directly to your HTML.

Comment: thanks, this solved the problem and you explained carefully ;)

Answer (score 0):

You must write `min-height` instead of `height`.

Answer (score 0):

The Problem seems to be your inline-style "height"

try

```
min-height:250px;
```

[link to example](https://www.bootply.com/pqHeWyd6Ab)

hope this fix your problem

Answer (score 0):

You can use `min-height` instead of `height`

```html
<div class="container">

<div class="row">
<div class="col-md-6" style="margin-bottom: 20px;">

<div class="col-md-12" style="min-height:250px; background-color: red; color: white;text-align: center; font-size: 18px;">

    <i class="fa fa-play" aria-hidden="true" style="font-size: 50px; padding-top: 60px;"></i><br>

    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. consectetur adipiscing elit.

</div>

</div>

<div class="col-md-6">

<div class="col-md-12" style="min-height:250px; background-color: green; color: white;text-align: center; font-size: 18px;">

    <i class="fa fa-play" aria-hidden="true" style="font-size: 50px; padding-top: 60px;"></i><br>

      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. consectetur adipiscing elit.

 </div>
 </div>

 </div>

 </div>

 <div class="container" style="margin-top: 20px;">

 <div class="row">
<div class="col-md-6" style="margin-bottom: 20px;">

  <div class="col-md-12" style="min-height:250px; background-color: red; color: white;text-align: center; font-size: 18px;">

    <i class="fa fa-play" aria-hidden="true" style="font-size: 50px; padding-top: 60px;"></i><br>

    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.consectetur adipiscing elit.

 </div>

</div>

 <div class="col-md-6">

  <div class="col-md-12" style="min-height:250px; background-color: green; color: white;text-align: center; font-size: 18px;">

    <i class="fa fa-play" aria-hidden="true" style="font-size: 50px; padding-top: 60px;"></i><br>

    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. consectetur adipiscing elit.

</div>

</div>

</div>
```